# What is the iTunes Connect role I need to add a new app?

Tags: app-store-connect

I don't see explicitly said in https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev82a173c41 what is the role I need. I guess it is 'admin', given 'Access to all sections within iTunes Connect.', but maybe other role can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Role Permissions](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/deve5f9a89d7) documentation includes a table **My Apps: App Store** that states **Create apps and submit versions** is available to:

- Legal
- Admin
- App Mgr

> ## iTunes Connect Developer Help
>
> ### Role Permissions > My Apps: App Store
>
> [image: iTunes Connect Developer Help: Role Permissions: My Apps: App Store]

Comment: true, although every time I try to create a new App I'm redirected to the initial page of iTunes connect...

Comment: and suddenly it starts working... wow...